# if you target two classes, how to then use this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

if I target two selectors like so for example

```
$('.menutxt, .submenutxt').hover(
  function() {
    jthis = $(this);
```

how does $(this) work?  Is there a way to get a specific one to be in that variable?

Comment: this is the hovered element.

Comment: which one, .menutxt or .submenutxt?

Comment: This is the element that triggers the hover, if you use $(this) in a .click(function(){}); $(this) is the element clicked

Comment: Well, the one over which the cursor is when the function is called.

Comment: @loriensleafs: Why do you think this is different from `$('.SomeClass')` if there are two elements with that class?

Comment: easy, goodness, I was just asking cause I wasn't sure

Comment: @loriensleafs. dont matter which, its the element hovered, if you want to know witch one is use $(this).attr("class") to get the class, you specified both selector for the function. Or you create one function for each class or you can test it inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an event handler, `this` is the **specific element** that triggered the event.

A single event can only come from one element.